# Totally unable to find jp.sourceforge.pdt_tools.formatter

Tags: eclipse-plugin, code-formatting, eclipse-pdt

I would like to add a PHP formatter to my Eclipse Helios (3.6 SR2) installation, but I'm not able to find any place to download a jp.sourceforge.pdt_tools.formatter (any version which can added to the Helios SR2)...

I searched 1 hour on google, on torrent sites, download programs like emule, on megaupload and other shared files system, but no result.

On the official website (http://de.sourceforge.jp/projects/pdt-tools/) project is closed and I can't find it on any site on the web...

If anyone has this jar file and can share it, it would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Totally?  Not even a little?  :)

Comment: Not totally. One of my friend gave me an old version (0.92.4) which not allow to format like I want :-(

Comment: I just installed 1.2.5 and have no idea how to enable/use it.  It shows up in my list of plugins, but Windows/Preferences -> PHP/Code Style/Formatter still only lets me pick between tabs and spaces.  Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only files I'm still able to find to download are here:
http://sourceforge.jp/users/atlanto/pf/eclipse/files/?id=477

v1.2.1 works in Eclipse Indigo with PDT 3.0.

Comment: I just installed 1.2.5 and have no idea how to enable/use it.  It shows up in my list of plugins, but Windows/Preferences -> PHP/Code Style/Formatter still only lets me pick between tabs and spaces.  Any help?

Comment: To install it you must use the Help -> install new software, and click on the "add" top-right button, and select the "archive" button in the new opened window. From here, you can select the archive you downloaded and it install properly the pdt-formatter. I find it under PHP/Code Style/Formatter (PDT Tools) and I must create a new profile and edit it to set my own settings. Hope this help...

Answer (score 0):

Try Eclipse [PHP Development Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt) project.

Answer (score 0):

@KRavEN Atlanto (the original author) is not maintaining the formatter plugin anymore so i've integrated the formatter from that plugin into my PDT extensions: https://github.com/pulse00/PDT-Extensions.

You'll find the updatesite for it on http://pulse00.github.com/p2/